# Getting faulting module OLEACC.dll, version 4.2.5406.0 error in Event viewer application log?

Tags: c++, windows

My application crashes with an error saying "Demo Application pk/si component has stopped working". The systems Event Viewer log shows an error with the following details.

**"Faulting application Demo.exe, version 1.0.0.1, faulting module OLEACC.dll,version 4.2.5406.0, time stamp 0x4549bd93,exception code 0xc0000005,fault offset 0x00004062,process id 0x154c,application start time 0x01c9ee94aab4c550"**

I am using Windows Vista Home Premium edition and the application which i created was a Vc++ SDI application.

Please let me know if anyone have come across this issue and what could be the possible solution for the same.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like good old access violation to me. It looks like you writing/reading from an invalid memory location in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a bug somewhere in your code that is passing invalid values to some Windows functions, and somewhere further down the line this results in a crash. Just because it isn't your DLL where the crash occurs doesn't mean it isn't your fault!

Although this isn't very helpful, all you can do is hook up a debugger to your program and reproduce the crash, then debug it.